# Haskell - check if there is a repeated element in the list

Tags: haskell

**This is a uni homework assignment that I have mostly finished and I'm not just coming here for answers**

The task given was to find if a given an element shows up more than once in a list. The algorithm I tried was to create `countDups` that will act as a counter, and count the amount of times said element is found in list. Then `isMemberTwice` (which should return a `Bool`) will be `True` if `countDups` is greater than 1 and `False` otherwise.

Yes I am new to Haskell so I'm sorry if this is a completely horrendous way to implement.

```
countDups x [] = 0 
countDups x (y:ys) 
    | x == y = 1 + countDups x ys 
    | otherwise = countDups x ys

isMemberTwice x [] = False      --base case; empty list
isMemberTwice x (y: ys) 
    | countDups > 1 = True 
    | otherwise False
```

**Error Message**

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Due to a comment below I updated but still not working - any suggestions?

```
isMember _ [] = 0
isMember a (x:xs)
    | (a == x) = 1
    | otherwise isMember a xs

isMemberTwice _ [] = False
isMemberTwice a (x:xs)
    | (a == x) = if ((1 + isMember a (x:xs)) > 1) then True
    | otherwise isMemberTwice a xs
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `=` before the last `False`. Because of the messed up Stackoverflow markdown, it's hard to say whether there actually are any indentation errors too, but I'm guessing no in this case. (There are other errors that will show up once it parses, though.)

Comment: Yeah I added the equal sign and got another error. Do you have a suggestion for a better algorithm?

Comment: Every `if` needs an `else` branch. I'd also add type annotations `isMember :: ...` before every function, since it is very common in Haskell to do so, both for documentation purposes and to improve GHC type error messages (if you state what you want, GHC can spot the differences).

Comment: If the elements in your list can be ordered (i.e. the element type is an instance of `Ord`) then you could also consider sorting the list and then looking if you can find two subsequent elements which are equal.

Answer (score 5):

Some tips:

1. Forget about `countDups` for now; you don't need it to write `isMemberTwice`.
2. Start by writing `isMember`.
3. Use `isMember` to write `isMemberTwice`.

   ```
    isMember x [] = ???
    isMember x (y : ys)
      | x == y = ???
      | otherwise = ???

    isMemberTwice x [] = ???
    isMemberTwice x (y : ys)
      | x == y = ???
      | otherwise = ???
   ```

Comment: Thank you! And not to be at all picky - just inquisitive. Would this produce a O(N^2) running time?

Comment: @a1yx, I've only given you a template. If you fill it in correctly, you should be able to demonstrate that it performs O(n) equality tests with O(n) administrative work.

Comment: Would you mind giving some pointers on the code from the edited question? I tried implementing your suggestion but I definitely messed up somewhere

Comment: @a1yx, your `isMember` seems to return a number for some reason, instead of a boolean. It should return a boolean. You don't need any numbers to solve this problem.